# How can I call a public function from a public shared function in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, webmethod

I have this code:

**Default.aspx(javascript:)**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowChartSpider(group_id) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Default.aspx/MethodToCreateChart",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'parameter1':" + JSON.stringify(group_id) + "}",

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("all correct");

                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
            );
        }
    </script>
```

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
  <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function MethodToCreateChart(parameter1 As String)

        WebChartControl1.Series("sectorbuys").Points.Add(New SeriesPoint("value1", "156"))

            WebChartControl1.DataBind()
        End If


        Return ""
    End Function
```

The code in view aspx from the chart is:

```
 <dxchartsui:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl1" runat="server">
// some code
    </dxchartsui:WebChartControl>
```

So in `MethodToCreateChart` I can't call my `WebChartControl1`, but if remove `shared` I can call the `WebChartControl1` control, but the ajax method stops working, so how can I call a control in my aspx keeping my 
 `Public Shared Function MethodToCreateChart`?

Answer (score 0):

PageMethod/WebMethod can access the session state but can't access the controls on the page, we can transfer the related property of control as a parameter that you want to get on WebMethod when you call WebMethod  on the client.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not quite understood your answer

Comment: can you make the webchartcontrol class shared?

Comment: webchartcontrol  is like an textbox or another control, is only an example, I have the same problem if I want to call this control:    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1">Example</asp:TextBox>

Comment: we can't access controls directly from webmethod/pagemethods, also the shared functions can call only call shared function within them, You can transfer the related property of control as a parameter that you want to get on WebMethod when you call WebMethod on the client. example something like this `PageMethods.MethodToCreateChart($get('WebChartControl1').value,"test", callback)`

Comment: and is posible to call this method? :     Public Function crearChart(ByRef path As String, ByRef group As String) As String,             from my MethodToCreateChart function?

Comment: yes it is you need to make the crearChart as shared too

Comment: yes but if I shared the last method, I can't get access to view controls, this is why I asking for?

Comment: For real projects that use SiteMaster, it won't work. MasterPage doesn't support JS PageMethods